# List of EE3 Add-ons, EE4-compatible out-of-the-box

Tags: compatibility, ee4

Sometimes is not official, but there are some EE3 add-ons not yet reported as EE4 compatible, but they are !

Here a list of EE3 add-ons tested on a fresh EE4 install, that works like a charm:

- CE Cache 2.0.2
- CE Image 3.0.1
- CE String
- Backup Pro
- Channel Polls 3.0.1

Comment: Republic Variables also works.  Didn't test all the functionality but almost all of it.

Comment: Juste tried Republic Variables and if i click "Parse variable early" i got an error  --> No such property: 'session' on EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Legacy\Facade
Any ideas?